# Is there such a thing as binary data censorship?

Tags: probability, survival, data-imputation

Let $X \sim Bernoulli(p)$, $Z \sim Bernoulli(\rho)$, and $X^* = Z * X$.

In other words, $X^*$ is "censored" with probability $\rho$. What type of censoring is this called?

Comment: This is not what is usually meant by censoring.  You are actually *altering* these data.  With censored data, an observation is either quantified or it has no numeric value at all but is accompanied by an indication that its value lies in a specific region.  With binary data, the only non-trivial form of censoring would be *missing* data.

Comment: @Jen Not in the usual mathematical sense of a composition of functions.  This is purely a product of random variables.  Such products are often used to describe a process in which certain values of one variable are replaced by a constant value.